# c++ RegSetValueEx sets only one char value in registry

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I'm casting (char * ) on data and i'm getting only one char value in the registry. if
i don't use the casting msvc 2010 tells me that the argument type LPCTSTR is incompatible with const char *.

can someone help me?

```
HKEY hKey;
LPCTSTR sk = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");

LONG openRes = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sk, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS , &hKey);

if (openRes==ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Success opening key.");
} else {
    printf("Error opening key.");
}

LPCTSTR value = TEXT("SomeKey");
LPCTSTR data = L"TestData\0";

LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx (hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)data, strlen(data)+1);

if (setRes == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Success writing to Registry.");
} else {
    printf("Error writing to Registry.");
}
cout << setRes << endl;

LONG closeOut = RegCloseKey(hKey);
if (closeOut == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Success closing key.");
} else {
    printf("Error closing key.");
}
```

Comment: Tom, it's third question in the last several hours related to the inconsistent usage of narrow and wide character strings. Instead of writing on SO every time you encounter a problem, maybe it would be better to review your entire code to remove these inconsistencies? Maybe, this article can help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strlen(data)` is probably returning a value of 1, as strlen expects a char* and `L"TestData\0"` is wide. Use `TEXT("TestData\0")` and call `_tcslen(data)`.
Note that `RegSetValueEx` expects the sizeof the data, so use `_tcslen(data) * sizeof(TCHAR)`

Comment: Looks like a better explanation/suggestion than mine :)

Comment: when i try to use this, for example LPCTSTR data = TEXT("ThisIsTheValueIWant\0"); then i get in registry only "ThisIsTheV" what should i do?

Comment: Answer modified to take this into account.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you casting data?

Either way, it looks like you may be working with wide characters, but you seem to be using "plain old" strlen - instead of wcslen or some other function intended to work with wide-character strings.

Answer (score 1):

replace the `L"TestData"` by `_T("TestData");` and `strlen(data)+1` by `tcslen(data) * sizeof(TCHAR));`

so your code looks like this :

```
LPCTSTR value = TEXT("SomeKey");
LPCTSTR data = TEXT("TestData");

LONG setRes = RegSetValueEx(hKey, value, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)data, _tcslen(data) * sizeof(TCHAR));
```